# Hibernate postgresql comparing date

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, date

I'm using Hibernate and PostgreSQL 8.4 database in a Java application. I have the following query:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from User where validStartDate < "  + getDate() +" and validEndDate >" + getDate());
```

where validStartDate is a Date in a PostgreSQL database and getDate returns a String from the current date by using the SimpleDateFormat.

But I keep getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: date < integer
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:192)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:451)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        ... 49 more
2010-11-29 20:42:19 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
2010-11-29 20:42:19 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ERROR: operator does not exist: date < integer
```

How do I cast the value so it is of proper type Date rather than integer?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If getDate() returns a String then you'll need to put it into single quotes. You are sending something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE validStartDate < 2010-11-29
```

which is read as "where the column validStartDate is lower than the result of calculating the result of 2010 minus 11 minus 29"

Now if you put 2010-11-29 into single quotes PostgreSQL will cast that String to a date but whether that will succeed depends on the formatting you apply in the SimpleDateFormatter

Edit: if you want to make sure the date literal is always treated correctly regardles of any client side locale settings, use a proper ANSI date literal:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE validStartDate < DATE '2010-11-29'
```

where the actual literal between the quotes has to be provided in the ISO formatted as shown above. Note the keyword *DATE* which specifies the ANSI date literal

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Using the *DATE '2010-11-29'* syntax will still be more robust and - as you are actuall providing a date - might be better from a performance point of view. Because no implicit casting takes place that might void the usage of any index

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using parameters in your query and let the postgres driver handling converting from Strings to the appropriate types/escaping for you - this is why parameterized queries exist.